# Save canvas created with fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

i want to store the canvas generated with the fabric.js, i have canvas as like below in my page

```
 <div class="canvas-container" style="width: 600px; height: 600px; position: relative; -moz-user-select: none;">
    <canvas height="600" width="600" id="design-stage" class="lower-canvas" style="position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none;"></canvas>
    <canvas class="upper-canvas " style="position: absolute; width: 600px; height: 600px; left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-user-select: none; cursor: default;" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    </div>
```

as said in the fabric.js documentation [serialization](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-3/#serialization) tried to save the canvas as json, but am unable to get the objects in the canvas it always returns empty as follows

```
{"objects":[],"background":""}
```

and my code to generate the json is follow

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('design-stage');
console.log(canvas);
var json = JSON.stringify( canvas.toJSON()  );
console.log(json);
```

Code to add the images on canvas

```
self._loadItemImage = function (url) { 
fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (img) { 
var w = img.width; var h = img.height;
 var size = self._resizeImage(w, h, self._width - 100, self._height - 100); 
 img.set({ left: self._width / 2, top: self._height / 2, originX: 'center', originY: 'center', hasBorders: false, hasControls: false, hasRotatingPoint: false, selectable: false, scaleX: 0.5, scaleY: 0.5 }); 
 self._motorImg = img; 
 self._canvas.add(self._motorImg);
 }); 
 };
```

Note:
Am not created objects using the functions in the fabric.js, i have loaded the svg images from a directory and added those images into the canvas by positioning the images

Comment: How are you adding objects to the canvas? Show us that code please.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv it is not done by simple code, i used more functions to add my object properties, so am unable to show the entire code, advice on this

Comment: First of all `JSON.stringify` is supposed to call `toJSON` on `canvas`, so calling `JSON.stringify` again is wrong. But `canvas.JSON` should _work_. If it does not work for you then you have: encountered a bug _or_ use an incompatible browser _or_ are doing something wrong in your own code.

Comment: canvas.JSON ? is this the function of fabric.js ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `canvas.toJSON`.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv it is not working

Comment: Well, as I said, it _should_ be working if you use it correctly. Show us the rest of the code.

Comment: why the down vote? let me know the reason, so i can understand what is the problem with my question. :)

Comment: Well, there you go. That's the reason for the downvote. (1) Pls show us the code. (2) No. (3) Downvote.

Comment: Now that we can actually see the code, back to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fabric.Image.fromURL` does some *asynchronous* stuff inside. The *callback* (`function (img) { ... }`) in your code will be called *after* the image is loaded. Though I cannot see the rest of the code I am sure you are calling `JSON.stringify(canvas)` right after calling `fabric.Image.fromURL` and are not *waiting* for the asynchronous image loading to complete.

Try this:

```
function Foo() {
    var self = this;
    self._motorImg = null;
    self._canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');

    self._loadItemImage = function (url) { 
        fabric.Image.fromURL(url, function (img) { 
            img.set({ left: 0, top: 0, originX: 'center', originY: 'center' }); 
            self._motorImg = img; 
            self._canvas.add(self._motorImg);

            self.debug('2');
        }); 
    };

    self.debug = function (when) {
        console.log(when, JSON.stringify(self._canvas));
    };


}

var foo = new Foo();
foo._loadItemImage('http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png');
foo.debug('1');
```

What you will surely notice is that `foo.debug('1')` outputs an empty canvas while `foo.debug('2')` outputs one where the image was added. Try it yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rqfLccq4/1/).

On the first `debug` call `function (url) { ... }` has not yet been called by `fabric.Image.fromURL`, thus the canvas is empty. You need to wait for it to be called, just like with any other AJAX request/callback.
So *any* code depending on that image to be loaded has to be called from that callback.

Comment: given fiddle is not working, and what you mean asynchronous? am using `canvas.toJSON()` to get the canvas as JSON on some button click, meaning that after all the canvas were loaded to the HTML.

Comment: What's not working? Open console and see the outputs of `console.log`.

Comment: yeah, i can see the console, sorry. However i want to know that i can get this objects, while click a button? actually what i did is. am doing this with a button. but it is not working to me.

Comment: If you click the button _before_ the image is loaded you'll get an empty canvas. So you should maybe also come up with a way of disabling that button before the image loads, just to be safe.